# Conky i3bar not recognizing spaces

Tags: i3, conky, fontconfig

I redid my i3bar recently with conky. This morning when I woke up the there were un-recognized characters symbols in my bar (where there are spaces in my conkyrc file)[image]. Nothing has really changed to my knowledge and I am not sure why this happened overnight. My conkyrc:

```
background no
out_to_x no
out_to_console yes
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0
use_spacer right

TEXT
${if_mpd_playing}${mpd_artist}   ${mpd_title}${endif}          \
  ${wireless_essid wlp7s0}          \
  ${exec amixer get Master | sed -n 's/^.*\[\([0-9]\+\)%.*$/\1/p'| uniq}          \
  ${cpu cpu}%          \
  $memperc%          \
  ${time %a %b %d}          \
  ${time %I:%M %P}          \
  ${battery_percent BAT0}% ${exec acpi -b | awk "{print $1}" | sed 's/\([^:]*\): \([^,]*\), \([0-9]*\)%.*/\2/'}
```

And my i3bar config:

```
bar {
        status_command conky -c $HOME/.i3/conky/conkyrc
        mode dock
        position top
colors {
        background #F1F2F6
        statusline #788491
        separator #51c4d4

        focused_workspace  #F1F2F6 #F1F2F6 #4FC0E8
        active_workspace   #F1F2F6 #F1F2F6 #4FC0E8
        inactive_workspace #F1F2F6 #F1F2F6 #C1D1E0
        urgent_workspace   #F1F2F6 #F1F2F6 #C1D1E0
    }
}
```

Comment: The lines in your post after TEXT start with a weird character in column 1. Is this an artifact of your copy/paste, or actually in the file? Try `cat -vet conkyrc` to check for non-printing chars.

Comment: Those are icons. This is the out of the vet https://pastebin.com/2wNnqa5K

Comment: U+0020 (presumably what the box with 0020 means) is the character code for space. Odd that it'd being displayed as a replacement character instead of a space...

Comment: Ok. My browser doesn't have the right fonts. You might try running conky with `--debug` or `-D -D` to see if it has any warnings. Note if you have conky version 1.10 it will be autoconverting your file to the new format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: updating the awesome font seemed to fix it.

```
pacaur -S awesome-terminal-fonts
```